# Go database/sql - Issue Commands on Reconnect

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

I have a small application written in Go that connects to a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database on another server, utilizing `database/sql` and `lib/pq`. When I start the application, it goes through and establishes that all the database tables and indexes exist. As part of this process, it issues a `SET search_path TO preferredschema,public` command. Then, for the remainder of the database access, I do not have to specify the schema.

From what I've determined from debugging it, when `database/sql` reconnects *(no network is perfect)*, the application begins failing because the search path isn't set. Is there a way to specify commands that should be executed when it reconnects? I've searched for an event that might be able to be leveraged, but have come up empty so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Connection_String_Parameters):

> **Connection String Parameters**
>   [...]
>   In addition to the parameters listed above, any run-time parameter that can be set at backend start time can be set in the connection string. For more information, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config.html.

Then if we go over to the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html), you'll see various ways of setting connection parameters such as config files, **`SET` commands**, command line switches, ...

While the desired behavior isn't exactly spelled out, it is suggested that you can put anything you'd `SET` right into the connection string:

```
connStr := "dbname=... user=... search_path=preferredschema,public"
// -----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and since that's all there is for configuring the connection, it should be used for every connection (including reconnects).

The **Connection String Parameters** section of the pq documentation also tells you how to quote and escape things if whatever `preferredschema` really is needs it or if you have to grab a value at runtime and add it to the connection string.

Comment: That was it! One quick follow-up - I read the page at the last link above, but I didn't see any verbiage that would imply (or suggest) the solution of putting those values in a connection string. Was it there, or is that suggested somewhere else?

Comment: Never mind - my blindness. It's right there in the `lib/pq` doc quote above.